# Browser treating real file differently than servlet-generated file

Tags: java, servlets, content-type, resources

I have an application that uses html5 to let the user listen to some audio samples on the server.  If I specify the path to an actual audio file on the server, things work as expected:

```
<audio src="/audio/english/banana_1.mp3" controls>
    Your browser does not support the <code>audio</code> element.
</audio>
```

However, if I point to a resource that is actually a servlet that generates the audio file, the audio doesn't seem to play:

```
<audio src="/app/dbAudio" controls>
    Your browser does not support the <code>audio</code> element.
</audio>
```

I've confirmed that this servlet does write out the required audio file; I have downloaded and played it back directly.  I have also set the response contentType to audio/mpeg and audio/x-mpeg but no dice.  Is there some other header that I need to set in order for this to work?  Thanks for any help.

```
  @RequestMapping(value = "/dbAudio", method = RequestMethod.GET)
  public void getAudioFromDB(HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception{

      response.setContentType("audio/mpeg");
      // Uncommenting the next allows me to download the resource directly and 
      // confirm that it is a well formed audio file
      // response.setHeader("Content-disposition", "attachment; filename=banana.mp3");

      OutputStream o = response.getOutputStream();

      Resource r = ctx.getResources("/audio/english/banana_1.mp3")[0];
      InputStream s = r.getInputStream();

      int chunk = 0;
      while(true){
          chunk = s.read();
          if(chunk == -1) break;
          o.write(chunk);
      }
      o.flush();         
  }
```

Comment: Get and compare response headers of both requests. If you stucks, add them to your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this [snippet](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Servlets/Sendmp3.htm).

Comment: I'm no expert, but maybe due to the content length?  http://www.w3.org/Protocols/HTTP/Object_Headers.html#content-length

Comment: Awesome, this link pointed out also setting the length of the response.  That fixe my problem.  Thanks.

Comment: Ah drat, I knew that. Some apps/plugins are indeed picky when it comes to the content length :) Glad it fixed your problem.